# libs folder not working in android studio while working with parse sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I have a problem in connecting my app with android,i have downloaded the sdk from  [parse.com](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing) and then  pasted the jar file in libs directory and also added the dependencies in my build.gradle

Still i cant access parse object plz anyone find me whats the problem.I hope this makes much more sense
First i have created an application in android studio and then i try to connect my app with parse.com so i downloaded that sdk and then i unzip the file and paste the parse jar file in the libs folder of my project,then paste these code in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
}
```

Still it is not referencing the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove bolts dependency, cause Parse's SDK already contains it. Be sure to click **Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with gradle files** after adding dependencies